# How can i create 2 buttons that will traverse a linked list and display the current node?

Tags: javascript

So currently I have created a linked list in javascript and the code executes when i click the "AddNode" button in my html file. This adds nodes to the empty list.

I have 2 other buttons that are supposed to traverse the list. These buttons are called "Previous" and "Next". When the list is empty and i click either previous or next, a message should display saying empty list. That is working fine.

When I have 1 node (the head node) that has populated the list and i press the "previous" button it does not display the message i am trying to output. this message is supposed to say the location of the node and that there is no previous node.

Please Assist.

I have tried changing my if statement and my print function.

the issue is on the "else if " portion of the function

```
function previousNode() {
    if (myList.head == null) {
        document.getElementById("trav").innerHTML = myList.print();
    }

    else if (myList.length == 1) {
        var x = "This is node " + (myList.length - 1) + ", also known as the head node.";
        document.getElementById("trav").innerHTML = x.print();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be the value of "x" under the "else if " statement but i am getting the error saying that "x.print()" is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are delcarating x variable as string type. you only need put this

```
document.getElementById("trav").innerHTML = x;
```